# Как прописать config для pdfkit для flask?

Tags: python, flask

Я собираюсь сделать деплой на heroku моё приложение и мне необходимо чтобы из моего `html` документа можно было бы сделать `pdf` файл.

Это легко достигается локально при помощи такого маршрутизатора:

```
# Route to create a PDF
@app.route('/<int:project_id>/create_pdf', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def create_pdf(project_id):

    config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf='C:\\WinDesign\\PROGRAMMES\\wkhtmltopdf.exe')

    project = Project.query.get_or_404(project_id)
    # return render_template('create_pdf.html', title=project.title,
    #                         date=project.date, post=project)
    html = render_template('create_pdf.html', title=project.title, date=project.date, post=project)
    pdf = pdfkit.from_string(html, False, configuration=config)
    response = make_response(pdf)

    response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/pdf"
    response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "inline; filename=output.pdf"
    response.headers
    return response
```

Однако при загрузке на `heroku` разумеется необходимый `wkhtmltopdf.exe` не находится так как он расположен на моей машине на диске С:

Я пробовал также этот файл попросту переписать в корень вместе с `app.py` однако это не помогло - на сайте при попытке создать `pdf` файл выпадает ошибка.

Как

Comment: Heroku - это фактически Linux система, никакие exe там работать не будут (без wine). Нужно гуглить как ставить wkhtmltopdf на heroku. Вот то что я нашел (но работоспособность не проверял): https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/wiki/Installing-wkhtmltopdf

Comment: Большое спасибо - нашла вот эту ссылку https://question-it.com/questions/690693/python-3-flask-ustanovit-wkhtmltopdf-na-heroku но не пойму как зайти в командную строку на heroku. Пробовала установить `pip install python-pdf` у себя, после сделала deploy - все равно ничего не работает. Не уверена что вообще в heroku что-либо установилось.

Comment: Еще вот это нашла https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/issueapp/heroku-buildpack-wkhtmltopdf но почему-то на этапе `git commit --allow-empty` открывается vim и непонятно что туда писать.

Comment: При коммите требуется указать описание коммита - или через ключ -m, потом в кавычках текст (git commit -m "Описание коммита"), либо прописать в открывшемся редакторе, сохранить, выйти из редактора.

Comment: Простите, не понимаю.. По вышеуказанной ссылке написано как установить wkhtmltopdf на heroku (если я правильно поняла). Я работаю в Atom в командной строке. Захожу в директорию с проектом - пытаюсь выполнить команду `heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/issueapp/heroku-buildpack-wkhtmltopdf` - получаю:  »   Error: Missing required flag:
 »     -a, --app APP  app to run command against
 »   See more help with --help

Comment: Я с heroku не работал. Ошибка говорит о том, что в командной строке нужно после `-a` указать имя приложения. Видимо это должно совпадать с тем именем приложения, для которого вы это все настраиваете.